# Ending a Functions Tkinter window from another Function

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tournament")
root.geometry("360x100")



def Choice():
    second = Toplevel()
    second.title("Tournament")
    second.geometry("360x100")
    command = root.withdraw()
    typechoice = Label(second, text = "Are you part of a Team or Solo?")
    typechoice.grid(row=0,column=0)
    solo1 = Button(second, text = "Solo", command = Soloscreen)
    solo1.grid(row=1,column=0)
    team1 = Button(second, text = "Team", command = Teamscreen)
    team1.grid(row=2,column=0)

def Soloscreen():
    third = Toplevel()
    third.title("Tournament")
    third.geometry("360x100")
    typechoice = Label(third, text="Enter your name")
    typechoice.grid(row=0, column=0)
    done = Button(third, text="Done")
    done.grid(row=1, column=0)

def Teamscreen():
    fourth = Toplevel()
    fourth.title("Tournament")
    fourth.geometry("360x100")
    typechoice = Label(fourth, text="Enter your name")
    typechoice.grid(row=0, column=0)
    done = Button(fourth, text="Done")
    done.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Creating GUI widgets
Start = Button(root, text="Start",width = "30", command=Choice, fg="red")
PHS = Button(root, text="Previous High Scores", width = "30", fg="red")
ENQ = Button(root, text="Enter New Questions", width = "30", fg="red")
# Displaying them on screen
Start.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
PHS.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
ENQ.grid(row = 3, column = 3)


root.mainloop()
```

As you can see here I have a pretty simple multiple window set up currently, what I dont understand is that I'm able to close the Root window with  command = root.withdraw()however under the Soloscreen and Teamscreen windows the same command but changed to close the Choice screen wont seem to work?

Comment: I think you should destroy these windows with `destroy()` function. Then create a custom function for all to re run them when needed. How would that work for you?

Comment: Also the way you are working with these functions is more complex than it should be.